# query mysql joining two tables and display specific of the second

Tags: mysql, join, difference

There is a main table called "tl_game" and a secondary table called "tl_times"

```
tl_game: game_id | day

tl_times: times_id| game_id| section_id | time
```

For each game row, there will be 28 rows in tl_times related (from section_id 1 to section_id 28)

Example:

```
tl_game: 
- 1 | 2-2-2020


tl_times:
- 1 | 1 | 1 | 15:00
- 2 | 1 | 2 | 15:10 
- 3 | 1 | 3 | 15:14 
- .....
- 28 | 1 | 28 | 16:18
```

I would like to write a query that gives me every game with the time difference between section 28 minus section 3

query result: 1 | 16:18 - 15:00

I have written the following query which seeems to be working but I don't know if it is very elegant. Any suggestions?

```
    Select p.id,(SELECT tf.time
                 FROM `test-local`.tl_times tf
                 Where tf.game_id = g.id
                 And tf.section_id = 28)
                 -
                (SELECT ti.time
                 FROM `test-local`.tl_times ti
                 Where ti.game_id = g.id
                 And ti.section_id = 3) duration
     From `test-local`.game g
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Papallot, thank you for your question. Can you please provide more details? I see you have two tables tl_game and tl_time, how are these tables related?

Comment: Hi, there is a foreign key on game_id of tl_times related to tl_game.